# C++ : undefined reference issue in a simple case of separate compilation

Tags: c++, inline

Given the below class definition in the header file - "class1.h"

```
#ifndef CLASS1_H
#define CLASS1_H

class class1
{
public:
    class1 &fcn();    
};

#endif
```

and the member function fcn is defined in the source file - "class1.cpp"

```
#include "class1.h"

#include<iostream>

inline class1 &class1::fcn()
{
    std::cout << "Welcome to Class1" << std::endl;
    return *this;
}
```

when the following code in "main.cpp" is executed

```
#include <iostream>
#include "class1.h"

int main()
{
    class1 myclass;
    myclass.fcn();
}
```

it produces the following error

```
C:\...\rough>g++ main.cpp class1.cpp && a
C:\...\Local\Temp\ccJvpsRr.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `class1::fcn()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What went wrong?

Comment: Why did you add `inline` in the definition? What were you hoping to achieve with that?

Comment: And how do you compile the code?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen The command for compilation is present above ( g++ main.cpp class1.cpp && a )

Comment: @UnholySheep I have tried adding the inline keyword in the declaration instead of the definition, but getting similar error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `inline` keyword is the problem. You are supposed to use that with functions that are *defined* in headers. In your case, remove it and it should work fine.

Comment: Yes, it works in this case. Could you please explain why the behavior breaks when the definition is present in a source file instead?

Comment: @schwillr If you put your function into a cpp file and then mark it `inline`, the definition will be present only in that cpp file. The idea is that the compiler needs to see the definition of the function to actually inline it.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: So does this partially act as a static keyword to limit the scope to the same file.

Comment: @InQusitive no, it doesn't. `static` functions are unrelated to each-other. You can have two functions named `void foo()` that do different things in different compilation units if they are defined `static`. But `inline` definitions must be identical, otherwise it is an [ODR](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) violation.